# XAML Databinding is overwriting properties in the View Model when they haven't been set

Tags: c#, datetime, data-binding, xamarin.forms

I am using Xamarin forms and the MVVM design pattern to build my app. I currently have a date entry form where the user can input a date and a time.

[image: The date time entry]

Obviously the goal is to set 2 `DateTime` variables with the values chosen in this date picker. The problem that I am having is all to do with the Binding properties, here is the XAML for these pickers:

```
<DatePicker x:Name="endDatePicker" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" Format="dd/MM/yyyy" Date="{Binding EventEndDate, Mode=TwoWay}" />
<TimePicker x:Name="endTimePicker" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" Format="HH:mm" Time="{Binding EventEndDate, Converter={StaticResource DateTimeToTimeSpanConverter},Mode=OneWay}"/>
```

and here are the properties they are bound to:

```
DateTime _eventEndDate;
public DateTime EventEndDate
{
    set
    {
        SetProperty(ref _eventEndDate, value);
    }
    get
    {
        return _eventEndDate;
    }
}
```

I am setting the values of these pickers on load, image the page as a create/edit page that I am reusing. When editing the view is populated with data from the View Model. If I bind these controls to my DateTime the `Get` method is called and the correct date (that I entered) is set in the view.... immediately after the `Set` method is called and the date time (19/03/2018) is set in this case HOWEVER the time of day changes from 9am to 12am (as if its a new date time).

Now what I think is going on is that I am setting the view and then immediately the view is setting the view model.... however I haven't done anything in the UI and now the UI & VM are out of sync. If a user clicked to edit and didn't touch the date, this control would be changed.

How can I stop my pesky view from updating my view model, when no change has occurred in the view!

Comment: Using the same property for date and time (both controls), wouldn't they overwrite each other?

Comment: Are you using the control directly, since you a naming them `x:Name="endTimePicker"` ?

Comment: @FrankNielsen Yes they end up overwriting each other (time pickers date is always 01/01/1901 & date pickers time is always 12AM. I'm not referencing them at all in code behind. The name doesn't need to be there (I believe I was when I first made the screen to give it dummy data quickly)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the `TimePicker` control requires a `TimeSpan` data type. You are correctly using a `Converter` to convert from `DateTime` to `TimeSpan`, but this is only a one-way binding. You could not do this other way around, which is also a problem, if you want to make the user pick time.

At the same time, when you use `DatePicker` to change the date value, the control does not care about the "time" part of the date and always defaults it to 12 AM. This causes `EventEndDate` property to be updated and it is set to `19/03/2018 12 AM`. This in turn causes the `TimePicker` to update and voila - you get your unexpected time :-) .

To solve this, you will have to do it a bit differently. You will have to separate the date and time into three exclusive properties - the complete `DateTime` and `DateTime` and `TimeSpan`.

### Example

```
DateTime _eventEndDate;

public DateTime EventEndDate
{
    get
    {
        return _eventEndDate;
    }
    set
    {
        SetProperty(ref _eventEndDate, value);
    }
}

public DateTime EventEndDateOnly
{
    get
    {
        return _eventEndDate.Date;
    } 
    set
    {
        EventEndDate = value.Date + EventEndTimeOnly;
    }
}

public TimeSpan EventEndTimeOnly
{
    get
    {
        return _eventEndDate.TimeOfDay;
    } 
    set
    {
        EventEndDate = EventEndDateOnly + value;
    }
}
```

Now instead of binding to `EventEndDate` directly, you bind to the new calculated properties:

```
<DatePicker x:Name="endDatePicker" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" Format="dd/MM/yyyy" Date="{Binding EventEndDateOnly, Mode=TwoWay}" />
<TimePicker x:Name="endTimePicker" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" Format="HH:mm" Time="{Binding EventEndTimeOnly, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
```

It is a mouthful solution, but still I find it pretty elegant and is probably the best solution you can have.

Comment: I ended up deleting my branch and rebranching, implementing the properties this way. It works, it's not ideal but perfectly functional, thanks!

Comment: It is a bit lengthy, but it fits the requirements of the two input controls. If you wanted to make a bit less redundant, you could wrap the two controls in a custom control that will have a DateTime bindable property and will contain this logic inside, so it will work as a black box while satisfying your requriements.